# Issue with svn commit running mvn release:prepare

Tags: svn, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to run mvn release:prepare and getting the following error.
I have a flat project structure. I am using SVN as source code management tool.

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: 'D:\home\dev\eclipse_workspace' is not a working copy
```

my release plugin is added to the parent pom as follows

```
<'plugin>
<'groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins'<'/groupId>
<'artifactId>maven-release-plugin'<'/artifactId>
<'version>2.1'<'/version>
<'/plugin>
```

Comment: May be you can show the POM here? Have you configured the connection and developerConnection in the SCM area of the pom ?

Answer (score 0):

The directory does not contain the .svn (hidden) folders. I suspect that you are trying to release a project from an exported directory, instead of having checked it out from svn first.
Maven needs the .svn folders when doing a release.
Also, you need to have committed all your changes and not have files/directories which aren't added yet.

Basically, you need to have a clean checkout with no local changes of any kind in order to get this to work.

In addition, if the above is the complete setup for the release plugin, you're missing the  and a few other things, so this will definitely not work. (But, you might also be inheriting these from somewhere; anyhow -- that's another problem).